# Recover windows 10 EFI Boot from dual boot with ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bootloader, efi, partition-recovery

I made my window 10 system system in dual boot with ubuntu. I would like to remove ubuntu and install it in virtual-box within windows.

I am afraid to remove ubuntu partions fearing windows may not boot after it. Currently I get ubuntu Grub screen on booting computer. How do I get my windows bootloader back so that I don't see grub screen again. Once I am able to do that I can delete ubuntu partions and merge it back with windows partitions.

Please help to get me my windows bootloader back.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to delete the EFI binaries of grub from the ESP (`$ESP/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi` and/or remove the EFI boot entry of grub with `efibootmgr -B`. The Windows Boot Manager should not have been touched by Ubuntu (`$ESP/EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi`) and it is discovered automatically by most UEFI (so you don't need to register it manually; `efibootmgr` should tell whether there's an existing entry for it as well).

($ESP is the mountpoint of the EFI System Partition, e.g. `/boot/efi`)

Answer (score 0):

## If your windows installation vanished after installing Linux

I had windows 11 installed on sda (hard disk) and Manjaro Linux installed on sdb (SSD). For some reason I reinstalled Manjaro on the same drive (sdb), and windows boot entry vanished.

I can see both EFI partition and C: partition exist and accessible but BIOS firmware settings or grub doesn't detect windows bootloader. efibootmgr shows windows bootloader but it removes windows bootloader when saved.

#### Solution

Use another windows computer or make a virtual box VM with windows and use Rufus to make a bootable windows USB. Boot up your computer using that, and select [Repair your computer] instead of installing.

Try "Startup repair". But it didn't work for me alone.

Open command line from windows recovery menu and type

```
BOOTREC /FIXMBR
BOOTREC /FIXBOOT
BOOTREC /ScanOS
BOOTREC /rebuildbcd
```

Then restart. When restarting boot up from the windows USB again, go to repair and run "Startup repair". Restart again. Hopefully you'll boot into your existing windows installation.